# Android app to turn off mobile data for certain apps

Tags: gratis, android, internet

I have Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with Android 5.1.1

I want to turn off the Wi-Fi and mobile data for a certain app (for example Messenger and things like that). Which specific app would recommend to achieve that?

Requirements:

- Works on non-rooted devices
- Stock Android OS
- Free

Comment: For mobile data that can be done with native Android features, but not for WiFi. Best approach is most likely a [firewall app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377), or an [app to deal with permissions](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_380). The former are available for rooted and non-rooted devices, the latter will require root.

Comment: And please don't cross-post your question, your answer is already there on our sister-site: [Turn off mobile data for certain apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/133106/16575). I've adjusted your post to be specific to this site, so it won't be considered a cross-post anymore. Good luck!

Comment: There are [no root firewalls](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=no%20root%20firewall&c=apps) available in the play store, but I haven't tried any of them out so I won't comment on them. I've tried a few root firewalls before switching back to avast mobile and all of them worked just fine on both my phones, able to block mobile and/or WIFI internet to selected apps, or 'white list' mode (reversing the 'black list').

Answer (score 1):

[Netguard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard) may be what you're looking for.

1) No root

2) 100% open source

3) Application based firewall for Mobile Data and Wifi.

4) There is also a allowed only when application is displayed. (For preventing background access)

> There is no other no-root firewall offering all these features.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard

[image: Netguard demo]